# React Native Layout Animation Not Animating? Or Doing It Wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I've followed a couple of good tutorials in using Layout Animation with react native. I cannot seem to get something so basic to animate. I am attempting to animate the Tab, when it has been clicked on, the flex size increase but in the mobile device, although the size does increase, it is static and no animation is applied. I'm testing this on an Android device.

Nav.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';

export class Nav extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            active: 0
        }
    }

    onTabPress(index) {
        // LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
        this.setState({ active: index });
        // LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ height: 56, elevation: 8, position: 'absolute', left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0, backgroundColor: this.props.color, flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                {
                    React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => (
                        React.cloneElement(child, {
                            index: index,
                            active: this.state.active === index,
                            onTabPress: this.onTabPress.bind(this),
                        })
                    ))
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Tab.js (`this.props.children` as shown above are a list of Tabs)

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback, StyleSheet, Animated, Easing, Platform, LayoutAnimation } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

export class Tab extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
        // LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    }

    handlePress() {
        if (this.props.active) return;
        // LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
        this.props.onTabPress(this.props.index);
        // LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    }

    render() {
        var active = this.props.active ? { flex: 1.75, top: 6 } : { flex: 1, top: 15 };
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this)}>
                <View style={[active, { alignItems: "center" }]}>
                    <Icon size={this.props.iconSize || 24} color={this.props.color || "white"} name={this.props.iconName} />
                    <Text style={{ color: this.props.color || "white" }}>{this.props.active && this.props.title}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback >
        );
    }
}
```

I've commented out the LayoutAnimation code blocks to clarify the areas where I have tried. I know i may be doing it wrong but I have followed these guides and it didn't work, so this code here was my attempt at trying to make it work my own way i guess. Thanks in advance.

https://blog.callstack.io/react-native-animations-revisited-part-i-783143d4884
https://medium.com/@Jpoliachik/react-native-s-layoutanimation-is-awesome-4a4d317afd3e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, seems that there was nothing wrong with my code. I went on http://snack.expo.io 
to test this on ios and the animation worked. When moved to android, it was acting up exactly the way it was for my android device. A quick google search after that lead me to this. 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5267.

Basically, you just write the following in the constructor of your code and it will work. You can perform further checks on it too to define that this code would only run on android by using `Platform.OS` and an if statement

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental &&   UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
}
```